# Get dates week by week using datetime on Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need a method that, given a date using datetime.now(), generates the following dates in a for loop.
I've tried to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

cont = 1
for cont in range(1, 50):
    time_now = datetime.now()
    time_ed = time_now.replace(day = cont)
    print(time_ed)
```

but once I reach the last day of the month, it crashes and says the following:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Is there a method where, when reaching the last day of the month, passes to the next and continues doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_now = datetime.now()

for cont in range(1, 50):
    time_ed = time_now + timedelta(days=cont)
    print(time_ed)
```

Couple of things changed from your original code:

1. No need for `cont = 1` as it is defined in the `for` loop anyways.
2. Defined `time_now` outside the `for` loop so it doesn't need to be recalculated on every iteration.
3. Instead of just replacing the day on the `time_now` object, I just created a new `timedelta` object with your desired number of days on each iteration to add on to `time_now`.